# How to access AzureAd ->Users and groups - User settings

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I want to access the

> Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory->User Settings

via a powershell commandlet.

Currently I have tried

> Get-MsolCompanyInformation

which gives limited data about these settings. Not all settings access (true/false) comes up with this commandlet.

Can someone give the commandlet(s) by which I can get whether these settings are enabled/disabled for a tenant?

Comment: The settings I am talking about are :1) Users can add gallery apps to their Access Panel
2) Guest users permissions are limited
3) Admins and users in the guest inviter role can invite
4) Members can invite
5) Guests can invite
6) Restrict access to Azure AD administration portal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, there is **no** command to list those informations in `msol powershell module` and `Azure AD powershell module v2`.

As a workaround, we can use role to control those permission.

We can use Azure AD powershell V2 to list roles:`Get-AzureADDirectoryRole`.
Then we can use this command to list the members of this role: `Get-​Azure​AD​Directory​Role​Member`.

To create role, we can list the role template with this commmand `Get-AzureADDirectoryRoleTemplate`

```
PS C:\Users> Get-AzureADDirectoryRoleTemplate

ObjectId                             DisplayName                        Description
--------                             -----------                        -----------
729827e3-9c14-49f7-bb1b-9608f156bbb8 Helpdesk Administrator             Helpdesk Administrator has access to perform common helpdesk related tasks.
f023fd81-a637-4b56-95fd-791ac0226033 Service Support Administrator      Service Support Administrator has access to perform common support tasks.
b0f54661-2d74-4c50-afa3-1ec803f12efe Billing Administrator              Billing Administrator has access to perform common billing related tasks.
4ba39ca4-527c-499a-b93d-d9b492c50246 Partner Tier1 Support              Allows ability to perform tier1 support tasks.
e00e864a-17c5-4a4b-9c06-f5b95a8d5bd8 Partner Tier2 Support              Allows ability to perform tier2 support tasks.
88d8e3e3-8f55-4a1e-953a-9b9898b8876b Directory Readers                  Allows access to various read only tasks in the directory.
29232cdf-9323-42fd-ade2-1d097af3e4de Exchange Service Administrator     Exchange Service Administrator.
75941009-915a-4869-abe7-691bff18279e Lync Service Administrator         Lync Service Administrator.
fe930be7-5e62-47db-91af-98c3a49a38b1 User Account Administrator         User Account Administrator has access to perform common user management related tasks.
9360feb5-f418-4baa-8175-e2a00bac4301 Directory Writers                  Allows access read tasks and a subset of write tasks in the directory.
62e90394-69f5-4237-9190-012177145e10 Company Administrator              Company Administrator role has full access to perform any operation in the company scope.
a0b1b346-4d3e-4e8b-98f8-753987be4970 User                               Every user is implicitly considered to be a member of the User Role.
f28a1f50-f6e7-4571-818b-6a12f2af6b6c SharePoint Service Administrator   SharePoint Service Administrator.
d405c6df-0af8-4e3b-95e4-4d06e542189e Device Users                       Device Users
9f06204d-73c1-4d4c-880a-6edb90606fd8 Device Administrators              Device Administrators
9c094953-4995-41c8-84c8-3ebb9b32c93f Device Join                        Device Join
c34f683f-4d5a-4403-affd-6615e00e3a7f Workplace Device Join              Workplace Device Join
17315797-102d-40b4-93e0-432062caca18 Compliance Administrator           Compliance administrator.
d29b2b05-8046-44ba-8758-1e26182fcf32 Directory Synchronization Accounts Directory Synchronization Accounts
2b499bcd-da44-4968-8aec-78e1674fa64d Device Managers                    Allows access to read and edit device properties.
9b895d92-2cd3-44c7-9d02-a6ac2d5ea5c3 Application Administrator          Application Administrator role has access to perform common application management related tasks.
cf1c38e5-3621-4004-a7cb-879624dced7c Application Developer              Application Developer role has ability to create single-tenant applications.
5d6b6bb7-de71-4623-b4af-96380a352509 Security Reader                    Security Reader allows ability to read security information and reports.
194ae4cb-b126-40b2-bd5b-6091b380977d Security Administrator             Security Administrator allows ability to read and manage security configuration and reports.
e8611ab8-c189-46e8-94e1-60213ab1f814 Privileged Role Administrator      Privileged Role Administrator has access to perform common role management related tasks.
3a2c62db-5318-420d-8d74-23affee5d9d5 Intune Service Administrator       Intune Service Administrator has full access in the Intune Service.
158c047a-c907-4556-b7ef-446551a6b5f7 Cloud Application Administrator    Cloud Application Administrator has the ability to create applications and update all cloud properties of applications.
5c4f9dcd-47dc-4cf7-8c9a-9e4207cbfc91 Customer LockBox Access Approver   Customer LockBox Access Approver has approval access to user data requests.
44367163-eba1-44c3-98af-f5787879f96a CRM Service Administrator          CRM Service Administrator has full access in the CRM Service.
a9ea8996-122f-4c74-9520-8edcd192826c Power BI Service Administrator     Full access in the Power BI Service.
95e79109-95c0-4d8e-aee3-d01accf2d47b Guest Inviter                      Guest Inviter has access to invite guest users.
b1be1c3e-b65d-4f19-8427-f6fa0d97feb9 Conditional Access Administrator   Allows management of all conditional access capabilities.
```

More information about Azure AD powershell V2, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0).

Comment: Thanks for replying. However, for now I don't want to control these settings, but just retrieve/get their value to check if they are set or not. Can that be done now, when we don't have a powershell cmdlet available?

Comment: @puneet For now, Azure AD powerShell V2 does not support this, here are the command list of Azure AD powershell v2, please check it.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0   please retrieve/get their value via Azure portal:)

Comment: Yes Sir, I get that. The Azure portal is definitely there. However, the specific requirement was to retrieve their values through powershell, which you say is not available. Is there a way through which the Microsoft exposed APIs, that these powershell commandlets could be using inside, be available for reference, so that I could use them instead , until some powershell commandlet becomes available?

Comment: @puneet I am checking on the query and would get back to you soon on this.

Comment: I really appreciate your attention towards this. Thank you.

Comment: @puneet unfortunately, I can't find some useful information about via Azure graph API to find those settings :(   You could give your feedback to this link, all of the feedback you share in this link will be monitored and reviewed by the Microsoft engineering teams. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback   thank you for your feedback.

Comment: Thank you very much. I shall be able to take it from here.